# One drive api secure url

Tags: javascript, onedrive

**Short:**

I am unable to find any setting in documentation [one drive api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/?view=odsp-graph-online) to get a file url that could not be accessed without access token

**Details:**

I tried different things with `queryParameters: "select=id,name,size,file"` but could not change the result

Using javascript API, when files chosen from one it gives an array named `values` in which each object contains properties like (some fake but sample values)

```
@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl: "https://public.sn.files.1drv.com/m7ZHglUdfkMkwg-qqnNj8"
@odata.context: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('D2CFA54CB9FFC341')/items/$entity"
id: "FA4454CB9FFC341!172"
name: "sada.pdf"
size: 4344
```

My code to get above results is

```
var odOptions = {
    clientId: "df45ae45-68bd-4568-a473-4159a1b16fc1",
    action: "download",
    multiSelect: true,
    // openInNewWindow: true,
    // advanced: {
    //     queryParameters: "/drive/root/children?select=id,name,size,file",
    // },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(555, response); 
    },
    cancel: function (response) { console.log(response); },
    error: function (e) { console.log(e); }
};
OneDrive.open(odOptions);
```

the problen is `https://public.sn.files..` public url (any one can access file without login using this url) unlike google drive which gives a secure url

Answer (score 1):

The `downloadUrl` is a short lived URL that is preauthenticated so that authorization is not required. Access control checks are instead performed on the request that returns the URL. A flow that's closer to what Google Drive utilizes would be to hit the `/content` endpoint for a specific file - this request requires an OAuth token to be provided and will return the binary content.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I am not a security expert, but like a lay man I think in case my url is visible in http request? one can perhaps note the short lived url (or only file id) and access that file which I dont want. Is there a way to get secure url which needs auth token in addition to url to access file?